# pgadmin4 package has no installation candidate

Tags: postgresql, 20.04, pgadmin

1 - Create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` and add a line for the repository

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
```

2 - Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
```

3 - install posgtresql

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12 postgresql-12 postgresql-contrib libpq-dev postgresql-server-dev-12
```

4 - install pgadmin 4

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin4
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package pgadmin4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'pgadmin4' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Removed `kubuntu` tag as there doesn't seem to be any reason for including it.

Comment: When you run `sudo apt update` do you see the line `http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main`

Comment: yes i see the line

Comment: @AhmedRabeaSmaha When installing pgadmin 4 try using `sudo apt install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2` command instead. Also you followed the instructions under Quickstart (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) exactly?

Comment: E: Package 'pgadmin4' has no installation candidate

E: Unable to locate package pgadmin4-apache2

Comment: follow the tutorial on this url (https://linuxhint.com/install-pgadmin4-ubuntu/)